# When i click to open a dialog, it shows at the button of the page

Tags: angular, dialog

Hello guys so i want to click on a button to open a dialog to show some infos, i got some code from angular material and still it doesn't work

it show me the results at the button of the page, i just want it like a popup and i can close it when i finish reading.

- So here is my button to open the dialog
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqWVs.png)
- and here the results
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG9ND.png)
- here is the code for the button and the function of it
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUvbS.png)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tSci.png)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier if I could see all related codes, but did you properly imported the "Dialog" in your module (app-module)?

```
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

and

imports: [ ....,
MatDialogModule
];
```

Comment: Yes, i did import MatDialogModule in my app.module file, which part of code you want to see ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i didn't import the angular material styles in angular.json, solved now!